# Filtra las filas de un dataframe si los valores de algunas columnas han cambiado

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo una dataframe y me gustaria obtener los `item_id` de los items por lo cual los `item_price` no varian:

```
         date  date_block_num  shop_id  item_id  item_price  item_cnt_day
0  02.01.2013               0       59    22154      999.00           1.0
1  03.01.2013               0       25     2552      899.00           1.0
2  05.01.2013               0       25     2552      899.00          -1.0
3  06.01.2013               0       25     2555     1709.05           1.0
4  15.01.2013               0       25     2555     1099.00           1.0
```

Por ejemplo aqui deberia obtener 22154, 2552.

Entonces intenté

```
d = {}
for row in transactions.iterrows():
    try:
        # Asseguremos que los precios de item_id no han cambiado
        d[row.item_id]['item_price'] != row.item_price:
            d.pop(row.item_id, None)
    # en el otro caso es que el item_id ya no esta una clave del diccionario
    except KeyError:
        d[row.item_id]['item_price'] = row.item_price
```

Pero obtengo:

```
  File "<ipython-input-22-06e70f158952>", line 5
    d[row["item_id"]]['item_price'] != row["item_price"]:
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: En los casos en que el precio aparezca una sola vez, como el item_id 22154 ¿no formaría parte del resultado también? Al fin y al cabo ya que solo tiene un precio, éste no varía. Por otro lado no entiend muy bien tu ejemplo, ya que dices que el resultado sería 2555 pero en ese item sí que ha variado el precio (tiene dos y los dos diferentes). ¿No debería ser 2552 el resultado?

Comment: @abulafia Me disculpe, si! Me equivoqué. En que el precio aparezca una sola vez, como el item_id 22154 deberia formar parte del resultado también con 2252

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre una solución que, aunque es un poco complicada de explicar, se reduce al final a dos líneas de código.

La idea es:

- Agrupar el dataframe por su columna `item_id` de modo que cada uno de esos grupos contiene todas las filas en las que `item_id` es el mismo.
- A cada grupo aplicarle la función `nunique()` sobre la columna `price_id`. Esta función te cuenta el número de valores no repetidos que aparecen. En tu ejemplo, para el `item_id` 2555 daría 2, ya que ese item tiene 2 valores diferentes. En cambio para los `item_id` 2552, 22154 daría 1 en ambos casos, uno porque sólo tiene un valor, otro porque aunque tenga dos valores son iguales.
- Quedarse con las filas en las que el paso anterior haya salido 1, y obtener el índice del resultado (ya que el resultado está indexado por los `item_id`.

Lo anterior se reduce a estas dos líneas:

```
>>> contadores = df.groupby("item_id").item_price.nunique()
>>> contadores[contadores==1].index.to_list()
[2552, 22154]
```